# back button navigation alert user

Tags: angularjs, browser-history

If the user presses the back button, i am displaying a confirm dialog. Based on the user choice in the dialog, navigation is prevented or continues.

Here is the code for the same:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e) {

            if(confirm('u want to leave the page?') != true){
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        });
```

its working fine. The problem i have is, lets say,

The user is in 'Page2' when he presses the back button(he came there from Page0 -> Page1 -> Page2), user stays in 'Page2' if he chooses cancel in the dialog. But when he presses back button again, it takes him to 'Page0'.

I need to keep the history from changing if he chooses to not navigate back in the dialog.
How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
window.history.back()

window.history.forward();
```

In order to navigate Browser History.

Full API is described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history